# What's the best way to find if the processor type is PPC or Intel in Cocoa? (Do I have to use Carbon?)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, hardware, macos-carbon

I need to get it as a string to use elsewhere in the program, I'm not worried about compiler settings.

I found [HowToGetHardwareAndNetworkInfo](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HowToGetHardwareAndNetworkInfo) on CocoaDev, but it seemed a little intense when all I wanted to know is PPC vs. Intel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your application is built fat (i.e. isn't running under rosetta on intel), you don't need to make any calls to get this information, because *different code will be running, depending on which architecture you're on*.  Thus, the information is available at compile time:

```
#if defined __i386__ || defined __x86_64__
NSString *processorType = @"Intel";
#elif defined __ppc__ || defined __ppc64__
NSString *processorType = @"PPC";
#elif defined __arm__
NSString *processorType = @"ARM";
#else
NSString *processorType = @"Unknown Architecture";
#endif
```

If you really want to do the determination at runtime for some perverse reason, you should be able to use the `sysctlbyname` function, defined in `<sys/sysctl.h>`.

Comment: Depending on the purpose, you may find the `__LITTLE_ENDIAN__` and `__BIG_ENDIAN__` macros more useful (especially if you intend to also support the iPhone, which is an ARM platform).

Comment: Given that the questioner wanted the values as strings, I assumed they weren't intending to use them to determine endianness.  I modified the example to include ARM, just in case.

Comment: I would prefer to figure out at runtime. It's nothing perverse, I just need to write it to a file config file. (For reasons are stupid and out of my control.)

Comment: Stephen's answer gives it to you at runtime.  Do that, then write `processorType` into your config file.

Comment: With what I gave you the answer is still *available* at runtime; it just avoids needing to do the *decision* at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

How about `uname`?

```
struct utsname uts;
uname(&uts);
printf("%s\n", uts.machine);
```

Will print like PPC or i386 or x86_64 depending on the machine.

Comment: That won't compile? "Storage size of 'uts' isn't known"

Comment: #include <sys/utsname.h> (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/uname.3.html)

Answer (score 0):

The only part of that mess which you actually care about is here:

```
host_info(mach_host_self(), HOST_BASIC_INFO, (host_info_t)&hostInfo, &infoCount);
```

See the Mach headers in Kernel.framework for struct and constant definitions.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that. What do I have to import? Which variables do I have to define? (I'm still unclear on how it works when you have to pass &references to C-functions.)

Comment: That's something you might want to read up on before writing software in C.